# Mod for Jelly Bean Nav bar on Kit Kat Tablet?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, 4.3-jelly-bean, user-interface

I have a Nexus 7 (2013), it is running kit kat, and I am really loving how everything I have set up in this ROM (Beanstalk 4.4.2). There is one thing I really miss and can't seem to find any information on, I would love to have the old Jelly Bean Navigation Bar/Soft Keys on the left combined with the status/notification bar on the bottom right again while in landscape.

I really don't understand why this feature was removed in Kit Kat. And have searched all over the place trying to find some type of relevant information on it. But its a hard thing to search for as there is no term that is associated with this UI layout. So far the only relevant info I have found is apparently Paranoid Android offered this feature in the settings of there Nexus 7 2012 ROM for Kit Kat.

I'd really like to stick with the ROM I have now if possible. Isn't there a mod or some xposed module or something that can offer this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For continuity across all Android device sizes, from phones to tablets, the Android team *completely removed* the old tablet layout from 4.4 going forward. It is no longer there so it isn't something that can just be switched on.

It would have to be built back into the ROM, so you may ask your ROM developer or look to see if a ROM has already done this.

Comment: Yeah exactly. Its very unfortunate that is gone as of 4.4. I'm sure I would of found it by now considering I tinker with things so much. I was just curious if there is a mod already made for this functionality.  If one were to implement this into a ROM what is it exactly that gives this layout? Is it just the Android UI framework itself? Like what is it someone should look for in the jelly bean source if one would want to include it in a custom kit kat build?

Comment: That I cannot answer. It may just be a part of android_frameworks_base but it likely includes many other parts. You would probably have better luck on the coding side by asking at Stack Overflow, as they are geared more to development.